# In C# - How to convert boolean values 'true' and 'false to "PRIME" and "NOT PRIME" respectively

Tags: c#, string, boolean

This is my code so far, but I'm not sure how I can make the result textbox show only "PRIME" as the message to the user if the condition is "TRUE" (instead of showing just "TRUE") or show "NOT PRIME" as the message to the user if the result is not a prime number i.e. FALSE instead of showing "FALSE" . This is a scientific calculator that calculates prime numbers btw.

This is my first post here and I am a beginner so any help in the right direction would be appreciated. Cheers.

```
protected void calculatePrimeNumberButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num = int.Parse(numberPrimeTextBox.Text);
    int divider = 2;
    int maxDivider = (int)Math.Sqrt(num);
    bool prime = true;

    while (prime && (divider <= maxDivider))
    {
        if (num % divider == 0)
        {
            prime = false;
        }

        divider++;
    }

    resultPrimeNumberTextBox.Text = prime.ToString();        
}
```

Comment: I really DON'T want to answer this question at all because the tiniest effort of research will get you to the right answer...

Comment: Only just started learning how boolean expressions work. As embarassing as it sounds I have been researching for a bit now haha, which is why I went through the trouble of posting up a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
resultPrimeNumberTextBox.Text = (prime) ? "PRIME" : "NOT PRIME";
```

This evaluates to

```
if (prime)
   resultPrimeNumberTextBox.Text = "PRIME";
else
   resultPrimeNumberTextBox.Text = "NOT PRIME";
```

Comment: This is how you create/feed a help vampire

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is a really helpful answer in combination with the answer above, to get me familiar with the 'ternary operator'. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do a simple check if prime set text box to "prime" else set it to "not prime". Don't do tostring on the boolean value.